# Is it possible to multiplex several channels into one?

Tags: concurrency, go, channel

The idea is to have a variable number of channels in a slice, push each value received through them into a single channel, and close this output channel once the last one of the input channels is closed. Something like this, but for a number of channels more than two:

```
func multiplex(cin1, cin2, cout chan int) {
    n := 2
    for {
        select {
        case v, ok := <-cin1:
            if ok {
                cout <- v
            } else {
                n -= 1
            }

        case v, ok := <-cin2:
            if ok {
                cout <- v
            } else {
                n -= 1
            }
        }

        if n == 0 {
            close(cout)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The above code avoids busy looping since there is no `default` case, which is good (EDIT: it looks like the presence of ", ok" makes the select statement non-blocking and the loop is busy after all. But for the sake of the example, think of the code as if it would block). Could the same kind of functionality also be achieved with an arbitrary number of input channels? Obviously, this could be done by reducing the slice pairwise to a single channel, but I would be more interested in a simpler solution, if possible.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe this snippet does what you're looking for.  I've changed the signature so that it's clear that the inputs and output should only be used for communication in one direction.  Note the addition of a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup), you need some way for all of the inputs to signal that they have completed, and this is pretty easy.

```
func combine(inputs []<-chan int, output chan<- int) {
  var group sync.WaitGroup
  for i := range inputs {
    group.Add(1)
    go func(input <-chan int) {
      for val := range input {
        output <- val
      }
      group.Done()
    } (inputs[i])
  }
  go func() {
    group.Wait()
    close(output)
  } ()
}
```

Comment: There is now a package with a function (https://godoc.org/github.com/eapache/channels#Multiplex) that solves the problem using reflection instead of multiple goroutines.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: added pairwise reduction example code and reordered parts of the answer.

The preferred solution is the non-answer of "restructure so that you don't have a slice of channels."  The restructuring can often make use of the feature that multiple goroutines can send to a single channel.  So instead of having each of your sources send on separate channels and then having to deal with receiving from a bunch of channels, just create one channel and let all the sources send on that channel.

Go does not offer a feature to receive from a slice of channels.  It's a frequently asked question, and while the solution just given is preferred, there are ways to program it.  A solution I thought you were suggesting in your original question by saying "reducing the slice pairwise" is a binary divide and conquer solution.  This works just fine, as long as you have a solution for multiplexing two channels into one.  Your example code for this is very close to working.

You're just missing one little trick to make your example code work.  Where you decrement n, add a line to set the channel variable to nil.  For example, I made the code read

```
    case v, ok := <-cin1:
        if ok {
            cout <- v
        } else {
            n--
            cin1 = nil
        }
    case v, ok := <-cin2:
        if ok {
            cout <- v
        } else {
            n--
            cin2 = nil
        }
    }
```

This solution does what you want and is not busy waiting.

So then, a full example incorporating this solution into a function that multiplexes a slice:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func multiplex(cin []chan int, cout chan int) {
    var cin0, cin1 chan int
    switch len(cin) {
    case 2:
        cin1 = cin[1]
        fallthrough
    case 1:
        cin0 = cin[0]
    case 0:
    default:
        cin0 = make(chan int)
        cin1 = make(chan int)
        half := len(cin) / 2
        go multiplex(cin[:half], cin0)
        go multiplex(cin[half:], cin1)
    }
    for cin0 != nil || cin1 != nil {
        select {
        case v, ok := <-cin0:
            if ok {
                cout <- v
            } else {
                cin0 = nil
            }
        case v, ok := <-cin1:
            if ok {
                cout <- v
            } else {
                cin1 = nil
            }
        }
    }
    close(cout)
}

func main() {
    cin := []chan int{
        make(chan int),
        make(chan int),
        make(chan int),
    }
    cout := make(chan int)
    for i, c := range cin {
        go func(x int, cx chan int) {
            for i := 1; i <= 3; i++ {
                time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
                cx <- x*10 + i
            }
            close(cx)
        }(i, c)
    }
    go multiplex(cin, cout)
    for v := range cout {
        fmt.Println("main gets", v)
    }
}
```

Comment: No, not quite. What I'm looking for as function with the signature `func multiplex(cin []chan int, cout chan int)`, i.e. one that can operate on an arbitrary number of input channels instead of being hard-coded to two.

Comment: The `func multiplex()` is recursive. If you look in the `default` case, it calls itself with half of the array, until it gets down to two.

Answer (score 0):

Using goroutines I produced this. Is it what you want ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func multiplex(cin []chan int, cout chan int) {
    n := len(cin)
    for _, ch := range cin {
        go func(src chan int) {
            for {
                v, ok := <-src
                if ok {
                    cout <- v
                } else {
                    n-- // a little dangerous. Maybe use a channel to avoid missed decrements
                    if n == 0 {
                        close(cout)
                    }
                    break
                }
            }
        }(ch)
    }
}

// a main to test the multiplex
func main() {
    cin := make([]chan int, 3)
    cin[0] = make(chan int, 2)
    cin[1] = make(chan int, 2)
    cin[2] = make(chan int, 2)
    cout := make(chan int, 2)
    multiplex(cin, cout)
    cin[1] <- 1
    cin[0] <- 2
    cin[2] <- 3
    cin[1] <- 4
    cin[0] <- 5
    close(cin[1])
    close(cin[0])
    close(cin[2])
    for {
        v, ok := <-cout
        if ok {
            fmt.Println(v)
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT : References :

http://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator

http://golang.org/ref/spec#Close

Comment: The docs say that if you read a value from a channel with ", ok", the operation doesn't block. The value of `ok` is then simply `false` and the execution continues. If this is correct (I'm new to Go and can't quite tell), then if the channel is empty but not yet closed, the `if ok` line would evaluate as `false` and execute the `else` branch.

But if you'd replace "v, ok := <- src" and the `if` with a select statement, then it might work. Got to test that. Thanks you for your reply, btw.

Comment: Where did you read that the operation doesn't block ? I don't find it and it doesn't seem to match what I observe. I read from the doc that it doesn't block *once the channel is closed*.

Comment: This seems to come from an older version of spec, e.g. [here](http://go.googlecode.com/hg/doc/go_spec.html?r=c64e293#Communication_operators), take a look at the last paragraph before "Method expressions". In the current version this passage is changed a bit, and says that "a zero value returned because the channel is _closed and empty_ (false)". This sounds like `false` is only returned after the channels is drained and closed, right? That would mean I'm mistaken.