# reflect.Select Function is need why? I assume it is because the channel has to be a reflection value?

Tags: go

Under what cases would **reflect.Select** be needed?

I have found examples, but the use of Select seems contrived.

Any example where reflect.Select is necessary over normal Select?

Comment: One example is selecting on a dynamic number of channels http://stackoverflow.com/q/19992334/714501

Comment: Or just selecting channels where the specific type is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

There was a [write-up recently](https://engineering.mongodb.com/post/multiplexing-golang-channels-to-maximize-throughput/) from the guys at MongoDB. Apparently this code is in production use in their `mongodump` utility.

The specific code that uses `reflect.Select` looks like this (from the article):

```
// Run multiplexer until it receives an EOF on the control channel.
func (mux *Multiplexer) Run() {
    for {
        index, value, recv := reflect.Select(mux.selectCases)
        EOF := !recv
        // note that the control channel is always at index 0
        if index == 0 {
            if EOF {
                return
            }
            muxInput, _ := value.Interface().(*muxInputSource)
            mux.selectCases = append(mux.selectCases, reflect.SelectCase{
                Dir:  reflect.SelectRecv,
                Chan: reflect.ValueOf(muxInput.collection),
                Send: reflect.Value{},
            })
        } else {
            if EOF {
                mux.writeEOF()
                mux.selectCases = append(mux.selectCases[:index], mux.selectCases[index+1:]...)
            } else {
                document, _ := value.Interface().([]byte)
                mux.writeDocument(document)[]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reasons I can think that they use `reflect.Select` instead of a straight `select`:

- The number of goroutines (and therefore the number of channels) is determined at runtime (using the `-j` flag). In fact, it seems to change dynamically with `append`. (credit to @cnicutar's comment)
- The type of the channel is determined at runtime. This allows their `muxInput.collection` type to be anything it wants. (credit to @JimB's comment)

Answer (score 0):

If  your  channels are  fixed, you can use select to watch them;
But if your channels is unfixed  and you want to watch them, you can use reflect.Select.

There are some code snippet

```
var (
      events  []reflect.SelectCase
      err     error
      lenHdr  = 3 // zk conn event chan, shutdown chan, children refresh chan
      lenCW   = len(z.ChildWatches)    // a channel slice:chan ChildWatche
      lenDW   = len(z.DataWatches)     //a channel slice:chan DataWatche
      lenEN   = len(z.EphemeralNodes)  //a channel slice: chan EphemeralNode
  )
  events = make([]reflect.SelectCase, lenHdr+lenCW+lenDW+lenEN)
  events[0] = reflect.SelectCase{Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: reflect.ValueOf(FreshChanConEvent())} // kick off the event loop
  events[1] = reflect.SelectCase{Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: reflect.ValueOf(z.shutdownChan)}
  events[2] = reflect.SelectCase{Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: reflect.ValueOf(z.refreshChildChan)}
  for i, _ := range z.ChildWatches {
      events[lenHdr+i] = reflect.SelectCase{Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf((chan zk.Event)(nil)))}
  }
  for i, _ := range z.DataWatches {
      events[lenHdr+lenCW+i] = reflect.SelectCase{Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf((chan zk.Event)(nil)))}
  }
  for i, info := range z.EphemeralNodes {
    events[lenHdr+lenCW+lenDW+i] = reflect.SelectCase{Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: reflect.ValueOf(info.Ch)}
  }

  for {
    chosen, value, ok := reflect.Select(events)
    if chosen == xxxxx {...}
```

This code is watching   channels array (z.ChildWatches、z.DataWatches、z.EphemeralNodes）