# Go fan-out, multiple broadcasts, unknown number of receivers

Tags: go, parallel-processing, goroutine

I need a way to signal from one main goroutine, an unknown number of other goroutines, multiple times. I also need for those other goroutines to `select` on multiple items, so busy waiting is (probably) not an option. I have come up with the following solution:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type signal struct {
    data     []int
    channels []chan struct{}
}

func newSignal() *signal {
    s := &signal{
        data:     make([]int, 0),
        channels: make([]chan struct{}, 1),
    }
    s.channels[0] = make(chan struct{})
    return s
}

func (s *signal) Broadcast(d int) {
    s.data = append(s.data, d)
    s.channels = append(s.channels, make(chan struct{}))
    close(s.channels[len(s.data)-1])
}

func test(s *signal, wg *sync.WaitGroup, id int, ctx context.Context) {
    for i := 0; ; i += 1 {
        select {
        case <-s.channels[i]:
            if id >= s.data[i] {
                fmt.Println("Goroutine completed:", id)
                wg.Done()
                return
            }
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("Goroutine completed:", id)
            wg.Done()
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    s := newSignal()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(3)
    go test(s, &wg, 3, ctx)
    go test(s, &wg, 2, ctx)
    go test(s, &wg, 1, ctx)

    s.Broadcast(3)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

    // multiple broadcasts is mandatory
    s.Broadcast(2)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

    // last goroutine
    cancel()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/dGmlkTuj7Ty

Is there a more elegant way to do this? One that uses builtin libraries only. If not, is this a safe/ok to use solution? I believe it is safe at least, as it works for a large number of goroutines (I have done some testing with it).

To be concise, here is exactly what I want:

- The main goroutine (call it `M`) must be able to signal with some data (call it `d`) some unknown number of other goroutines (call them `n` for `0...n`), multiple times, with each goroutine taking an action based on `d` each time
- `M` must be able to signal **all** of the other `n` goroutines with certain (numerical) data, multiple times
- Every goroutine in `n` will either terminate on its own (based on a context) or after doing some operation with `d` and deciding its fate. It will be performing this check as many times as signaled until it dies.
- I am **not** allowed to keep track of the `n` goroutines in any way (eg. having a map of channels to goroutines and iterating)

In my solution, the slices of channels do **not** represent goroutines: they actually represent signals that are being broadcast out. This means that if I broadcast twice, and then a goroutine spins up, it will check both signals before sleeping in the `select` block.

Comment: This is not safe, at least in the sense that `test` function will wait until you close the 0th channel. It will only detect closing of  channels in order. If you can describe what exactly you want to achieve, better ways of doing it can be suggested.

Comment: I think what you have described is actually a feature that I need (that's why I implemented it in this somewhat bizarre way). I will add more details shortly

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992334/how-to-listen-to-n-channels-dynamic-select-statement

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I believe that code is doing the opposite of what I am trying to do: it is listening to n goroutines from 1 goroutine. I am trying to broadcast from 1 goroutine to n goroutines. The solutions describe what is basically a channel multiplexer, which might also work (I will try it soon). Apologies in advance if my analysis is wrong, I am not super familiar with this stuff yet (I have also edited my answer with more details)

Comment: Is it the case that you want to write once to a channel, and have n goroutines read that data? You can have a goroutine that  listens to that broadcast channel, and sends the data to n listeners/

Comment: That is an idea I had, but the problem is that I couldn't find a way to implement it without keeping track of the n listeners (I used a map). Is there a way that does not keep track of the listeners at all?

Comment: You are keeping track of all the signals sent now. You have to keep track of something.

Comment: Haha, I suppose you are right in that aspect. I believe in my applications signals are fairly low in number, while listeners may be high. What is your evaluation of my current solution then, based on the constraints?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you might want something like a fan-out pattern. Here's one [source](https://medium.com/@thejasbabu/concurrency-patterns-golang-5c5e1bcd0833#8954) describing fan-in and fan-out, among other concurrency patterns. Here's a [blog post](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) on golang.org about this too. I think it's essentially a version of [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) using channels.

Basically, you want something, say `Broadcaster`, that keeps a list of channels. When you call `Broadcaster.send(data)`, it loops over the list of channels sending `data` on each channel. `Broadcaster` must also have a way for goroutines to `subscribe` to `Broadcaster`. Goroutines must have a way to accept a channel from `Broadcaster`or give a channel to `Broadcaster`. That channel is the communication link.

If the work to be performed in the "observer" goroutines will take long, consider using buffered channels so that `Broadcaster` is not blocking during `send` and waiting on goroutines. If you don't care if a goroutine misses a `data`, you can use a non-blocking send (see below).

When a goroutine "dies", it can `unsubscribe` from `Broadcaster` which will remove the appropriate channel from its list. Or the channel can just remain full, and `Broadcaster` will have to use a [non-blocking send](https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations) to skip over full channels to dead goroutines.

I can't say what I described is comprehensive or 100% correct. It's just a quick description of the first general things I'd try based on your problem statement.

Comment: while this is true, I wanted a solution that did not require keeping track of listeners in any way