# Unable to loop through golang dynamic channels

Tags: go, dynamic, goroutine, channel, trayicon

I want to loop through the menu's options. However, it stops at the first option, since the select without "default:" is blocking and it does not know more options will appear dynamically.

Bellow is the broken code:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/getlantern/systray"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

var menuItensPtr []*systray.MenuItem
var config map[string]string
var commands []string

func main() {
    config = readconfig()
    systray.Run(onReady, onExit)
}

func onReady() {
    systray.SetIcon(getIcon("assets/menu.ico"))
    menuItensPtr = make([]*systray.MenuItem,0)
    commands = make([]string,0)
    for k, v := range config {
        menuItemPtr := systray.AddMenuItem(k, k)
        menuItensPtr = append(menuItensPtr, menuItemPtr)
        commands = append(commands, v)
   }
   systray.AddSeparator()
    // mQuit := systray.AddMenuItem("Quit", "Quits this app")
    go func() {
        for {
            systray.SetTitle("My tray menu")
            systray.SetTooltip("https://github.com/evandrojr/my-tray-menu")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for{
            for i, menuItenPtr := range menuItensPtr {
                

          select { 
/// EXECUTION GETS STUCK HERE!!!!!!!
                case<-menuItenPtr.ClickedCh:
                    execute(commands[i])
                }
            }   
            // select {
            // case <-mQuit.ClickedCh:
            //  systray.Quit()
            //  return
            // // default:
            // }
        }
    }()
}

func onExit() {
    // Cleaning stuff will go here. 
}

func getIcon(s string) []byte {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    return b
}

func execute(commands string){
    command_array:= strings.Split(commands, " ")
    command:="" 
    command, command_array = command_array[0], command_array[1:]
    cmd := exec.Command(command, command_array ...)
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // fmt.Printf("Output %s\n", out.String())
}

func readconfig()  map[string]string{
    yfile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("my-tray-menu.yaml")
    if err != nil {
         log.Fatal(err)
    }
    data := make(map[string]string)
    err2 := yaml.Unmarshal(yfile, &data)
    if err2 != nil {
         log.Fatal(err2)
    }
    for k, v := range data {
         fmt.Printf("%s -> %s\n", k, v)
    }
    return data
}
```

Bellow is the ugly workaround that works:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/getlantern/systray"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

var menuItensPtr []*systray.MenuItem
var config map[string]string
var commands []string
var labels []string
var programPath string

func main() {
    setProgramPath()
    config = readconfig()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    systray.Run(onReady, onExit)
}

func onReady() {
    systray.SetIcon(getIcon(filepath.Join(programPath,"assets/menu.ico")))
    menuItensPtr = make([]*systray.MenuItem, 0)
    i := 0
    op0 := systray.AddMenuItem(labels[i], commands[i])
    i++
    op1 := systray.AddMenuItem(labels[i], commands[i])
    i++
    op2 := systray.AddMenuItem(labels[i], commands[i])
    i++
    op3 := systray.AddMenuItem(labels[i], commands[i])
    i++

    systray.AddSeparator()
    mQuit := systray.AddMenuItem("Quit", "Quits this app")
    go func() {
        for {
            systray.SetTitle("My tray menu")
            systray.SetTooltip("https://github.com/evandrojr/my-tray-menu")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
// HERE DOES NOT GET STUCK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            case <-op0.ClickedCh:
                execute(commands[0])
            case <-op1.ClickedCh:
                execute(commands[1])
            case <-op2.ClickedCh:
                execute(commands[2])
            case <-op3.ClickedCh:
                execute(commands[3])
            case <-mQuit.ClickedCh:
                systray.Quit()
                return
            }
        }
    }()
}

func onExit() {
    // Cleaning stuff will go here.
}

func getIcon(s string) []byte {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    return b
}

func setProgramPath(){
    ex, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    programPath = filepath.Dir(ex)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func execute(commands string) {
    command_array := strings.Split(commands, " ")
    command := ""
    command, command_array = command_array[0], command_array[1:]
    cmd := exec.Command(command, command_array...)
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Output %s\n", out.String())
}

func readconfig() map[string]string {
    yfile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filepath.Join(programPath,"my-tray-menu.yaml"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    data := make(map[string]string)
    err2 := yaml.Unmarshal(yfile, &data)
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err2)
    }

    labels = make([]string, 0)
    commands = make([]string, 0)

    for k, v := range data {
        labels = append(labels, k)
        commands = append(commands, v)
        fmt.Printf("%s -> %s\n", k, v)
    }
    fmt.Print(len(labels))
    return data
}
```

Full source code here:
https://github.com/evandrojr/my-tray-menu

Comment: There are two approaches: 1) The "fan in" pattern: spawn a separate goroutine to read from each of the channels and make them send _something_ into a single channel which is then monitored by your select statement. That something can be the channel itself. 2) The `reflect` package has a way to "listen" on a slice of channels. I strongly recommend to consider the first approach first.

Comment: To elaborate on the fan-in pattern: as long as you make the receiving side be able to easily determine the source of event, this approach can funnel events from multiple sources into a single consumer without it having to know about all that sources itself.

Comment: Hi @kostix thanks, I like the "fan in" pattern. I have seen it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992334/how-to-listen-to-n-channels-dynamic-select-statement I just don't know how to apply to my situation. I don't use Go for my daily work. I use it for  tiny projects like that. I have made the same project in Kotlin and it was really simple. To be honest I didn't manage to pop up the menu with the left mouse button, only the right button. Then I decided to give it a go to Go. Learning hurts, but I enjoy it, lol. I would be very glad if you could show me a working example. Thanks! :)

Comment: Rob pike has a great talk about multiplexing in go: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs
He covers the fan-in and fan-out patterns

Comment: Hi @John, great video Rob Pike's video! I wish I had seen it before hitting my head against the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`select`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Select_statements) "chooses which of a set of possible send or receive operations will proceed". The [spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Select_statements) sets out how this choice is made:

> If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection. Otherwise, if there is a default case, that case is chosen. If there is no default case, the "select" statement blocks until at least one of the communications can proceed.

Your working example:

```
select {
    case <-op0.ClickedCh:
        execute(commands[0])
    case <-op1.ClickedCh:
        execute(commands[1])
    // ...
}
```

uses `select` successfully to choose between one of the offered options. However if you pass a single option e.g.

```golang
select { 
    case<-menuItenPtr.ClickedCh:
        execute(commands[i])
    }
}
```

The `select` will block until `<-menuItenPtr.ClickedCh` is ready to proceed (e.g. something is received). This is effectively the same as not using a select:

```golang
<-menuItenPtr.ClickedCh:
execute(commands[i])
```

The result you were expecting can be achieved by providing a default option:

```golang
select { 
    case<-menuItenPtr.ClickedCh:
        execute(commands[i])
    }
    default:
}
```

As per the quote from the spec above the `default` option will be chosen if none of the other options can proceed. While this may work it's not a very good solution because you effectively end up with:

```
for {
   // Check if event happened (not blocking)           
}
```

This will tie up CPU time unnecessarily as it continually loops checking for events. A better solution would be to start a goroutine to monitor each channel:

```golang
for i, menuItenPtr := range menuItensPtr {
    go func(c chan struct{}, cmd string) {
        for range c { execute(cmd) }
    }(menuItenPtr.ClickedCh, commands[i])
}
// Start another goroutine to handle quit
```

The above will probably work but does lead to the possibility that `execute` will be called concurrently (which might cause issues if your code is not threadsafe). One way around this is to use the "fan in" pattern (as suggested by @kostix and in the [Rob Pike video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs) suggested by @John); something like:

```golang
cmdChan := make(chan int)

for i, menuItenPtr := range menuItensPtr {
    go func(c chan struct{}, cmd string) {
        for range c { cmdChan <- cmd }
    }(menuItenPtr.ClickedCh, commands[i])
}

go func() {
    for {
        select { 
            case cmd := <- cmdChan:
                execute(cmd) // Handle command        
           case <-mQuit.ClickedCh:
                systray.Quit()
                return
        }
    }
}()
```

*note: all code above entered directly into the question so please treat as pseudo code!*

Comment: I had neglected to include a loop in the last example; fixed that now so it should process multiple messages. The first approach should work (but I would not advice it and tight loops can have unexpected side effects); unfortunately the link you provided is broken.

Comment: Since it cannot be edited after 5 minutes I've fixed the link and posted again the comment:

Hi @Brits, many thanks for your answer. The second approach “a goroutine to monitor each channel” so far is the only one that worked for me. I have posted it here: https://github.com/evandrojr/my-tray-menu/blob/dynamic_channels_brits/main.go The first option with default value does not work for me (I also have tried before) and the “fan in” solution only executes for the 1st time.

Comment: I'm assuming that, as you accepted the answer, the amended "fan in" option worked for you (sorry the amended comment confuses things a bit because it now appears after my comment :-) ).

Comment: Approaches 2 and 3 are working now, many thanks again @Brits! I guess one of the side effects of a tight loop is not allowing enough time to listen for IO changes. If you are really curious about it give yourself a try. But it is not really necessary. I am ashamed of myself for not seeing your mistake. I guess I was anxious to enjoy the sunday. At least I’ve refactored some of my bad code.

Comment: Hi @Brit

Maybe for you the "default:" select option will, work for me it didn't:

Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description: Linux Mint 20.2
Release: 20.2
Codename: uma

Anyway the "fan in" pattern seems to be the best approach. Should work for everybody and doesn't waste cpu cycles.

Comment: Yes - I would not bother going any further with the `default` select option. It's not something you would want to do in a production system as it needlessly wastes CPU cycles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247128/discussion-between-evandro-jr-and-brits).